# Function that replaces vowels in textfile with "_"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function that replaces all vowels in a text file with "_"
this is my code so far:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
wordfile= open(filename)
one_line = wordfile.readline()

for ch in one_line:
    if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
        print one_line.replace(ch,"_")

one_line = wordfile.readline()
wordfile.close()
```

my textfile has the words "tick tock around the clock"
It's output should be:

```
t_ck t_ck _r__nd th_ cl_ck
```

however this is my output instead:

```
t_ck tock around the clock
tick t_ck ar_und the cl_ck
tick tock _round the clock
tick t_ck ar_und the cl_ck
tick tock aro_nd the clock
tick tock around th_ clock
tick t_ck ar_und the cl_ck
```

Could someone explain why it isn't all in one line?

Comment: You `print` every iteration of your loop, instead re-assign like `one_line = one_line.replace(ch,"_")` then `print` at the end outside the loop. Incidentally the Pythonic way to do this would probably be with `str.maketrans()`

Comment: You did not mark any answer as selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax:

```
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```

The method `replace()` returns a `copy` of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting the number of replacements to max.

So when you do:

```
for ch in one_line:
    if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
        print one_line.replace(ch,"_")
```

you are not replacing the `one_line`

---

to get the expected result you need to update your `one_line` as follows:

```
for ch in one_line:
    if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
        one_line = one_line.replace(ch,"_")
print(one_line)
```

---

However, the solution suggested by "Zohaib Ijaz" is way better:

```
data = re.sub("[aAeEiIoOuU]+", "_" ,data)
```

Comment: cf my answer, your regex is missing the `re.DOTALL` flag (the `s///g` parameter ) as is, it will only replace the first occurences.

Comment: @zmo, the regex does not need `re.DOTALL`, and it *does* replace all occurrences. See my comment to yours under my answer as well.

Comment: cf comment under my answer, *mea culpa*.

Answer (score 0):

Put print line outside the for loop.

```
for ch in one_line:
    # YOUR CODE

print one_line
```

UPDATE

Full code:

```
for ch in one_line:
    if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
        one_line =  one_line.replace(ch,"_")

print one_line
```

Comment: That will just print the original line.

Comment: I put a comment saying YOUR CODE inside for loop because his logic is correct. it's just his print statement that's at the wrong place.

Comment: If you look at the user's last output line (``tick t_ck ar_und the cl_ck``) you will see that it's **not** "``just his print statement that's at the wrong place``".

Comment: No, @PrakharVerma, it wont work by just moving it out of the loop. Try it. strings are immutable.

Comment: Ok my mistake. I though that was quite obvious and he will be able to do it. Editing my answer right away. Thanks guys. Sometimes assumptions kill you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving updates made on `one_line` along loop occurrences.

You must *save* updates in a variable at each loop occurrence to got final result.

```
filename = 'test.txt'
wordfile= open(filename)
one_line = wordfile.readline()

output = one_line
for ch in one_line:
    if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
        output = output.replace(ch,"_")

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over every character in your input, and print the whole line if there is a character match. So this happens several times. Furthermore, in that print you only replace occurrences of one character. Be aware that the string is not changed by applying `replace`to it. Only the return value has the replacement done.

You can do it with one less loop, but assign the result of the `replace` call back to the string variable:

```
for ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
    one_line = one_line.replace(ch,"_")
print (one_line)
```

Consider using `re.sub` for doing it in one operation:

```
import re
print (re.sub('[aeiouAEIOU]', '_', one_line))
```

Comment: cf my answer, your regex is missing the `re.DOTALL` flag (the `s///g` parameter ) as is, it will only replace the first occurences.

Comment: @zmo, by default `re.sub` will replace all occurrences (this can be influenced by the `count` argument). The `re.DOTALL` flag is about something else entirely, and is useless for this regular expression, since it has no dot. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: cf comment under my answer, *mea culpa*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can replace you vowels

```
 data = wordfile.read()
 data = re.sub("[aAeEiIoOuU]+", "_" ,data)
```

Now write updated text back to file

### Example

```
data = 'Hello ) world Reply ( some text ) and some Reply ( more text ) and that is ) it.'
data = re.sub("[aAeEiIoOuU]+", "_" ,data)
```

> Output: 'H_ll_ ) w_rld R_ply ( s_m_ t_xt ) _nd s_m_ R_ply ( m_r_ t_xt ) _nd th_t _s ) _t.'

Comment: cf my answer, your regex is missing the `re.DOTALL` flag (the `s///g` parameter ) as is, it will only replace the first occurences.

Comment: @zmo I've tested before adding this answer. I've added an example with sample input and output.

Comment: cf comment under my answer, *mea culpa*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is it just reads one line of the file

Try this code where it will read all the lines in the file and per line it will scan all the letters and replace vowels into **_**

```
filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        print "".join(map(lambda x: '_' if x in "aeiouAEIOU" else x, line))
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's reformat a bit your code to match modern python practices:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as wordfile:
    one_line = wordfile.readline()

    for ch in one_line:
        if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
            print(one_line.replace(ch,"_"))
```

### what's wrong in your code:

- you're iterating over each character of the line for each voyel you know of, and then you're printing one character replaced by voyel, so you're printing `len(one_line)` the replacements.
- the [replace function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) returns a new string, with the replacement you've asked done, cf the documentation:

> *Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new*

so each time your'e iterating over a voyel you're still modifying the original string.

### How to improve that?

`replace` works over the full string, so you don't need to do the iteration over the characters of the line, but you can just iterate over all the voyels, and replace them in the string by replacing the string by the new string out of replace:

```
filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as wordfile:
    one_line = wordfile.readline()

    for c in 'aoeui':
        one_line = one_line.replace(c,"_")
        one_line = one_line.replace(c.upper(),'_')

    print(one_line)
```

but the issue here, is that you still have to iterate over `'aoeui'` and replace twice one_line for each voyel.

We can do better.

And, I believe that's what was your intention when you wrote the above algorithm:

```
new_line=''
for c in one_line:
    if c.lower() in 'aoeui':
        new_line += c
    else:
        new_line += '_'
```

this is more efficient, but way too much verbose. So yes, we can do better, we can use a [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html):

```
one_line = ''.join(map(lambda c: '_' if c.lower() in 'aoeui' else c, one_line))
print(one_line)
```

there's also the possibility to write this using a list comprehension:

```
one_line = ''.join(['_' if c.lower() in 'aoeui' else c for c in one_line])
print(one_line)
```

here, we just build a new string so that for each character of `c`, if `c` is a voyel (whatever the character case is), replace it with `_` or leave it as is otherwise. Then the `''.join()` method is just to make a string from a list.

Finally there's an even better method to fix that, it's to use a regex:

```
import re
re.sub('[aoeui]', '_', one_line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(one_line)
```

how does that work? It's actually building what's called finite state automaton that will be equivalent as the above map, and either place a `'_'` or the original character in the output string.

N.B.: the `IGNORECASE` flag is to enable checking of both `aoeui` and `AOEUI` without repeating yourself.

Comment: Your explanation of the `DOTALL` flag is wrong. Worse is that you comment on other posters saying they need `DOTALL` also, while this is not the case.

Comment: hm… I actually read on that a bit of the doc too fast. Though there's an issue that blocked it with `re.IGNORECASE`, made me assume wrong. So *mea culpa* for all my comments, and thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: ok, I accept penance for having misread the prototype of `sub()`, the fourth position of `re.sub()` is `count` and not flags, explaining the weird behaviour that had me pull my `PCRE` regex reflexes.